# Communicating data between two unrelated components

Tags: angular

I have a list of stores displayed in an unordered list and when this list is initialised the `ngOnInit()` function returns the data for all the stores.  When clicking each of the list elements I'd like to send the store data to the store detail component so it can work out the appropriate data to display.  How can I do this as these two components don't follow the parent/child relationship?  I'm new to the latest version of Angular so I'm not sure, perhaps an emitter or Rxjs is the way to go?

My template:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <div class="dropdown {{showMenu ? 'show' : ''}}">
        <button (click)='toggleMenu()' class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="">
          Stores
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu {{showMenu ? 'show' : ''}}" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
          <button (click)="clickStore()" class="dropdown-item" type="button" [routerLink]="['/store/1']">Store 1</button>
          <button (click)="clickStore()" class="dropdown-item" type="button" [routerLink]="['/store/2']">Store 2</button>
          <button (click)="clickStore()" class="dropdown-item" type="button" [routerLink]="['/store/3']">Store 3</button>
          <button (click)="clickStore()" class="dropdown-item" type="button" [routerLink]="['/store/4']">Store 4</button>
          <button (click)="clickStore()" class="dropdown-item" type="button" [routerLink]="['/store/5']">Store 5</button>
          <button (click)="clickStore()" class="dropdown-item" type="button" [routerLink]="['/store/6']">Store 6</button>
          <button (click)="clickStore()" class="dropdown-item" type="button" [routerLink]="['/store/7']">Store 7</button>
          <button (click)="clickStore()" class="dropdown-item" type="button" [routerLink]="['/store/8']">Store 8</button>
          <button (click)="clickStore()" class="dropdown-item" type="button" [routerLink]="['/store/9']">Store 9</button>
          <button (click)="clickStore()" class="dropdown-item" type="button" [routerLink]="['/store/10']">Store 10</button>
          <button (click)="clickStore()" class="dropdown-item" type="button" [routerLink]="['/store/11']">Store 11</button>
          <button (click)="clickStore()" class="dropdown-item" type="button" [routerLink]="['/store/12']">Store 12</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</li>
```

My store list component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.storeService.getStores().subscribe({ 
        next: stores => {
            this.stores = stores;
        },
        error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    });
}



clickStore(): void {
    console.log(this.stores);
    // send "this.stores" to store detail component
}
```

My store detail component:

```
export class StoreDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  retrieveStoreData(): void {
     // get data from store list component and assign to this.stores
  }


   displayStore(): void {
       let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

       for(let i=0;i<this.stores.length; i++){
          if(this.stores[i].storeId == id){
            this.store = this.stores[i];
          }
       }
   }


}
```

In the store detail template I simply want to show the store data:

```
ID: {{store.storeId}}

Name: {{store.storeName}}

Description: {{store.storeDescription}}
```

Comment: You're already doing it: youpass the D of the store in the URL, and the detail component uses this ID to get the details of the store. Call a new method `this.storeService.getStore(storeId)` to get the details of the store from your service. The details component doesn't need the list of stores. It needs the details of the store to display

Comment: @JBNizet that's assuming he has an endpoint to retrieve a store by id (I know it's more or less the norm, but still) and the listing doesn't have all the data he needs alerady, and so he doesn't need an additional http request for the details. The ideal in such case would be to store the list in the service and retrieve it by injection it into the details component.

Comment: No. If the list is stored in the service anyway, call `this.storeService.getStore(storeId)` and let the service return the requested store by looking inside the list. Whether the service retrieves the list every time, or caches the list, or hits a separate endpoint to get the details of one store should be irrelevant to the component: it should always get the store by asking the service.

Comment: That's fair, you're right. We are saying much of the same thing, but you are correct in that what you said doesn't exclude it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  I've got it working now.  Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a service to retrieve and store the data in a local property. That way you can access it by injecting the service into your components. A state management solution would work, yes, but a simple injectable service does the trick for such a simple use case.